# jQuery .ajax() - add query parameters to POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

To add query parameters to a url using jQuery AJAX, you do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'www.some.url',
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
      param1: 'val1'
  }
)}
```

Which results in a url like `www.some.url?param1=val1`

How do I do the same when the method is POST? When that is the case, `data` no longer gets appended as query parameters - it instead makes up the body of the request.

I know that I could manually append the params to the url manually before the ajax request, but I just have this nagging feeling that I'm missing some obvious way to do this that is shorter than the ~5 lines I'll need to execute before the ajax call.

Comment: Good point, as asked it is nearly a duplicate, but I made a mistake when writing the question - what I really should be asking is not "when the contentType is application/json", but rather "when the method is POST." I will update the question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) allows you to serialize the properties of an object as a query string, which you could append to the URL yourself:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.example.com?' + $.param({ paramInQuery: 1 }),
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    paramInBody: 2
  }
});
```

Comment: Which works if the base url doesn't already have params, which isn't a robust solution. I can of course use `$.param()` to create a query string and then do something like `url += (url.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + queryString;` to safely append the query string, but that becomes a monstrous one-liner, or I have to prepare the url before I actually call ajax. Which is certainly effective, but not ideal. If someone doesn't suggest something better I will accept this.

Comment: You can introduce your own property, `query`, and include it as an option in your `$.post()` calls. Then write a [pre-filter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) to do the nasty query string manipulation behind the scenes, away from the rest of your code.

Comment: The custom param + pre-filter seems the neatest to me.

Comment: @fildred13 could you please post your solution? I have the same situation: adding an GET Parameter to an `$.post.. `, but the URL sometimes already have GET Parameter, sometimes not, so that `url: getMyUrl+'?'+$.param({ paramInQuery: 1 }),` will not work in every case.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Ates Goral for the `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()` tip. My problem was I could not change the `url` because it was bound to `kendoGrid` and the backend web API didn't support `kendoGrid`'s server paging options (i.e. `page`, `pageSize`, `skip` and `take`). Furthermore, the backend paging options had to be query parameters of a different name. So had to put a property in `data` to trigger the prefiltering.

```
var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
    // options here...
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: httpRequestType,
                beforeSend: authentication.beforeSend,
                data: function(data) {
                  // added preFilterMe property
                  if (httpRequestType === 'POST') {
                      return {
                          preFilterMe: true,
                          parameters: parameters,
                          page: data.page,
                          itemsPerPage: data.pageSize,
                      };
                  }

                  return {
                      page: data.page,
                      itemsPerPage: data.pageSize,
                  };
              },
          },
        },
    },
});
```

As you can see, the `transport.read` options are the same options for `jQuery.ajax()`. And in the prefiltering bit:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) {
    // only mess with POST request as GET requests automatically
    // put the data as query parameters
    if (originalOptions.type === 'POST' && originalOptions.data.preFilterMe) {
        options.url = options.url + '?page=' + originalOptions.data.page 
            + '&itemsPerPage=' + originalOptions.data.itemsPerPage;

        if (originalOptions.data.parameters.length > 0) {
            options.data = JSON.stringify(originalOptions.data.parameters);
        }
    }
});
```